# Android 4.4 and Above - WebView Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid

Tags: android, web, android-webview

When I try `loadUrl("convert2mp3.net")`, nothing happens and logcat (in eclipse) it says:
**"W/cr.BindingManager(31239): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid"**

In forums, people suggests to use `setDatabaseEnabled(true);` but it is not working.

This problem only occurs on Android 4.4 and above.

Comment: I have similar problem. Any workaround?